# Split string between two characters

Tags: string, vbscript

Within a vbs script, I'm trying to get some characters between two characters.

e.g.

"C:\temp\98542\orange\myfile.txt"

want **98542**

OR

"C:\temp\748\apple\myfile2.txt"

want **748**

I'm not sure what the best method (Split function?) is to get out these number characters and assign it two a new variable?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know that it is always going to follow c:\temp\ ?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = Split("C:\temp\98542\orange\myfile.txt","\")(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, and the one that's "best" depends on your requirements. You can write your own code that uses `Mid` to get one character at a time. Or you can use `Split` if you know that this number is always in the same place in the filename. Or you can use a regular expression, which will take less code. What's "best" is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.split("C:/temp/98542/orange/myfile.txt", "/")[2];